# GL drawing Textures binding error

Tags: java, opengl

When I draw an image and then I try to draw and other geometry(2D), like a line or square... It wont work because the image is still bounded to GL (image.bind()). There is not method in the Texture class to un-bind the image. How do I unbind a image from GL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenGL you would call `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)`. Now if you use JOGL you can call `Texture.disable()`. However make sure you read the performance tips in any case

Comment: Well this works but I have found that static textures in classes only draw once for every update. Is that a thing or is it just me ?

Comment: @ExotickBoyPl sorry it is not clear what you are asking. Do you mean that for every geometry you draw, you use its texture only once per frame? If yes, then that is normal as far as the performance is acceptable to you. If you meant something else please provide further clarification

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. I mean that all the other textures work well but the static textures only draw once per frame

Comment: @ExotickBoyPl I don't understand the term: "static textures", nor how you have discovered that they are drawn only once (how many times they should be drawn per frame?). Perhaps if you add more details or maybe a code example of how you create/use those textures I could help further.

Comment: by static I mean that the texture is stored as a public static Texture

Comment: @ExotickBoyPl Oh you mean the java class field is static. Hmm I have never encountered such a case before. What you describe sounds like multiple objects are using the same Texture. If after drawing, the texture is disabled and the rest of the objects expect to find it enabled, then you could easily have a scenario like the one you describe

Comment: Well yes but I do not disable textures or change any thing between the draws... Could it be that I am binding the same image 2 times in a row ?

Comment: @ExotickBoyPl No as far as I know binding the same texture is not a problem. Perhaps you could move this to a new question with some code? (because SO displays a warning for extended discussion)